# Show extra option in the ribbon based on item path

Tags: c#, sitecore, ribbon

I'm using Sitecore 8 Update 2.
I need to create some archive functionality.

So I was going to add a new item at the same level as the home item and give the users a button in the ribbon. When they click this button the current item is moved to the archive item ( the archive item would have the same structure as the home item ).

When a user is working on an item in the archive, the option to archive the item shouldn't appear in the ribbon. Instead it should have a button to restore the item to its original place.

All I've been able to find is how to add ribbon sections based on its template, but that doens't help me much here.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is nice explanation how to add a button (command) to Sitecore ribbon:
[Adding a custom button to the ribbon](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/morten-ljungberg-sitecore-whats-new/posts/2015/08/adding-a-custom-button-to-the-ribbon.aspx).

To check whether button should be displayed or not, override `QueryState` method. You can return `CommandState.Enabled`, `CommandState.Disabled` or `CommandState.Hidden`, e.g.:

```cs
public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) context, "context");
  if (context.Items.Length != 1)
    return CommandState.Hidden;
  Item item = context.Items[0];
  if (item.TemplateID == ...) 
    return CommandState.Enabled;

  return CommandState.Hidden;
}
```

Then override `Execute` method and do your logic there:

```cs
public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) context, "context");
  if (context.Items.Length != 1)
    return;
  Item item = context.Items[0];
  ...
}
```